# does jquery plugin deleted when DOM element removes

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Simple plugin:

```
(function ($) {
   var MyTest = function (){
     this.bigarr = new Array(20000);
     this.init();
   };
   $.fn.extend({
     mytest: function(options){
     return this.each(function() {
        new MyTest();
     });
   }
 });

 $.extend(MyTest.prototype, {
  init: function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Then i attach the plugin to a DOM element:

```
$('#selector').mytest();
```

and remove the element:

```
$('#selector').remove();
```

What happens with the plugin? Does the big array still exist in memory? Or do I have to remove it manualy?

Comment: i dont really understand your question. `.remove()` simply remove the selected element. you can still use ur plugin

Comment: Ofcourse i can. But when i attache plugin to another element i create new MyTest instance. It seems to be a memory leak, if old instance is not deleted automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Calling remove on a jQuery selector removes the element from the DOM tree, but not from memory.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785258/how-to-remove-dom-elements-without-memory-leaks) for more discussion.

ian.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you never assign an instance of MyTest to a variable, it can be immediately garbage collected. The memory can be reclaimed whether or not you remove the element.

Comment: But MyTest is inside of closure. And i can use it anytime until element $('selector') being removed. So how browser is knowing about will i use MyTest or not?