# Iframes and memory management in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management, iframe

I have links that load pages into iframes. I have been monitoring the accumulation of data in memory using Google Chrome's memory heap profiler and I noticed some leaks in memory.

I loaded the page and took the first snapshot which added up to `2.69 MB`. I clicked the link that opens a page into an iframe and took another snapshot giving me `14.58 MB` in total. I removed the iframe using the following jquery snippet:

```
$('#myframe').unbind();
$('#myframe').remove();
/*
* By the way, I also tried $('#myframe > *') as a selector. 
* It still didn't work. Even if it would, it doesn't look like a viable solution to me.
* It looks too resource intensive.
*
* I forgot to mention that I am not using Ajax to load my pages
*/
```

I took another snapshot and got `5.28 MB` which indicated a deviation of `2.59 MB` from the initial value, which according to my understanding indicates memory leackage.

Now, my question is: If I remove an iframe (which includes the document loaded in it) doesn't the garbage collector find it necessary to also remove all the objects contained in that document from memory? Or will I have to do this manually?

I thought that if I load a document into an iframe, it's size will not affect the memory use on the parent page. I though it will be considered a separate window, but obviously that wasn't a well informed assumption on my part.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Thank you.

Comment: This thread seems to be a good entry point for this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785258/how-to-remove-dom-elements-without-memory-leaks .

Comment: What happens to the memory after the parent window is unloaded?

Comment: Thanks. If I refresh the parent window, the memory goes back to `2.69 MB`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the iframe, trigger a reload before removing it and then remove it.

```
<a href="#">Remove</a>
<iframe src="url" />​

$('a').click(function(){
    $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('iframe').remove();
    }, 1000);
});​
```

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/DfAp9/1/).

Addionally, you can do a manual cleaning up too - i.e. if you have data in your cookies or HTML5 localStorage.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $(document).unbind().die();    //remove listeners on document
    $(document).find('*').unbind().die(); //remove listeners on all nodes
    //clean up cookies
    /remove items from localStorage
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't resolve my iOS web view memory leak

Comment: Thanks Robin, First option which you shared is fantastic and it worked. I open 8 iframes and I gained 20 MB and after closing all of them and cleaning the way you explained I could reclaim all of the 20 MB back. superb Robin sir...

Comment: Do you know how I can do something like this when my Iframe does not load an actual URL but instead injects HTMML and JS and CSS scripts into a generated Iframe?

Comment: The workaround is working for me! Nobody opened a ticket to Google from 2012 up to now probably...

Comment: Warning! This does not work! In Chrome v116 this is even worse then calling just .remove() on iframe

Answer (score 2):

If any objects from the iframe is referenced in a object in the main window that object won't be removed from the DOM, so, if you have something like this:

Main window:

```
var object = {};
function iframe_call(data){
    object.iframe_data = data.something
}
```

iframe:

```
function onClick(){
    parent_object.iframe_call(this);
}
```

this happens especially if you refer DOM objects.

Comment: Thank you Cuzzea. I see your point, but I am not interacting with anything within the iframe at this stage. I've just been loading random pages. Right now I have not made any connection between the iframe and parent window. Besides, I also remove the iframe along with it's contents.

Comment: you can check to see exactly what changed comparing the 2 profiles. You can see winmerge to do a line by line compassion. Don't forget to order by constructor so the order is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
frame.src = "about:blank";
```

This worked from me and prevented memory leaks. Ig you must destroy the parent of the iframe, do it with some delay to prevent memory leak