# Does removing an iframe free up the memory taken by its JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, browser, garbage-collection

I think that **parsed/evaluated JavaScript**, *not objects created by that JavaScript upon execution, rather the space taken up by the code itself*, will remain in memory as long as you are on the page, even if you deleted the original **script node** from whence that JavaScript came. (Er, is that true?)

However, I'm wondering -- if that JavaScript lives inside an **iframe**... and that iframe is deleted from the containing **document's tree**, and all references to that iframe element are nulled out, so that **garbage collection** should do its thing...  will the browser free up the memory taken by the evaluated script that was in that iframe?

Comment: speaking generally, yes.

Comment: what's a good way to verify this for a given browser? i thought a ghetto way to do it would be to gin up a ginormous amount of code, stick it in an iframe and then unload that iframe, and just use system profiler to see the memory usage before-and-after for that process. Is that a reliable way to go about it?  Or is there something more under-the-hood in Chrome etc that would give me a more direct view of how memory is being allocated? I don't think I'll be able to understand the huge Chrome codebase well enough to determine for sure what it's doing in this area, but maybe that's a route too?

Comment: chrome had dev tool feature called timeline. record a snapshot while you load and remove the frame, then stop and click the memory tab. looks to me like adding a frame increase ram and removing it decreases ram back to where it was before adding...

Comment: An iframe (any frame) is a whole separate thread with its own garbage collection. Ever get the "Cannot access freed script" from IE? That's when you were referencing a variable created in another window/frame but the frame has been unloaded and its code garbage collected. The easiest way for you to try is to store a variable from the frame, remove the frame and try to use that variable afterwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframes and memory management in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript)