# Is it possible to fix memory leak from third-party ads?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, ads, google-dfp

I'm getting a consistent memory leak on Playlist.com using Google DFP advertising - leaving the tab open, it consistently uses more and more memory (only when the ads are enabled).

A sample test page that reproduces the leak can be found here: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6278910/ad-memory-leak.html.

Is there anything that can be done on our end to help mitigate the leak?  Obviously shutting off the ads is not a possible solution, financially.

**Edit:**  You can open developer tools in Chrome and try a memory timeline - every time the ads load, they use up slightly more memory.

Comment: Do the ads load in an `iframe`?

Comment: The ads themselves do, yes, though Google DFP runs as a script

Comment: You can check the sample page to see what's going on...

Comment: would it be possible to move the entire ad and the Google scripts into another iframe? This would isolate it from  your page.

Comment: Possible, though the ads are rendered as iframes by DFP, so I'm not sure what benefit doing so manually would provide...

Comment: The point of David's comment is that the "Google DFP [that] runs as a script" could then be run within this iFrame and not within your page. (Then the ad would be an iframe within the iframe). Hopefully reloading this first iFrame periodically would free any memory that was leaked by the script on that page.

Comment: Definitely report the problem to Google. This will matter to them and truly they should fix it or disable leaky ads. Web site publishers should not have to work around this. See the AdSense Help Center https://support.google.com/adsense/?hl=en#topic=1190787

Comment: Yeah, I could try the ads-in-iframe approach - we did report to Google and they are investigating.

Comment: Hey, @JacobGillespie . Did you find the solution, we have faced into this problem too, and have no idea what to do

Comment: @Mikhail - we didn't find a direct solution no - Google DFP kinda acknowledged the issue but said they had other priorities to fix first.  In the end we built our app to automatically refresh the page every so often to help lower memory usage.

Comment: @JacobGillespie did the ads-in-iframe approach actually work? Have you tried this approach?

Comment: @mkhatib - it helped but didn't fully solve the issue.  We ended up going with a full page refresh every so often to fully purge the memory.

Comment: @mkhatib - I should note that it seemed that with the iframe solution you needed to load two different pages, not just refresh a single page.  Something like loading ads1.html, then on "refresh" load ads2.html in the iframe and switch between the two.  Simply refreshing ads1.html didn't lower memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, try to reload the iframe to clean the DOM before removing it, then add it again. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript):

```
<a href="#">Remove</a>
<iframe src="url" />​

$('a').click(function(){
    $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('iframe').remove();
    }, 1000);

    ... add add iframe again ...
});​
```

Depending on how this is made there could some flickering of the adds, but it should not be major. The adds already refresh themselves after a while, so if this is done one add iframe at a time the user would not notice.

Comment: Interesting approach - I tried entirely deleting the parent div and reinitializing the ads routinely and that didn't work, but I did not try refreshing...  I'll add and test.

Comment: It didn't work - the sample page above now has a button that triggers this code, but it's not really helping the memory issues.

Comment: try to compare two snaspshots with the chrome profiler, one when the memory starts leaking and the other where the leak is very pronounced, see this tutorial to compare two snapshots http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ugr9BJqIs check for unexpected retaining paths