# Clear memory after iFrame is closed

Tags: javascript, memory, iframe, memory-leaks

How to correctly close / remove the iframe from the page that would free up the memory?

noticed that when you open the main page of other iframes, memory is consumed more and more, but if you just delete the iframe, memory cleaning will not happen.

How to be?

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript) method.

I created this code (do not judge strictly, did it in a hurry):

```
(function ($) {
    $ .fn.purgeFrame = function () {
        let frame = $ (this);
        frame.each (function () {
            let _frame = this;
            $ (_ frame.contentWindow) .off ();
            let doc = $ (_ frame.contentWindow.document);
            doc.find ('*'). off (). remove ();
            doc.off ();
            doc.empty ();
            $ (_ frame) .remove ();
        });
    };};
}) ($);
```

Iframe is gone, but the memory is cleared all a couple of mb, while it took about 20.

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript

Comment: @BharathSampathKumar I already found this solution, but it did not bring any special results. More I described in the header above.