# Is it beneficial to hide elements not in use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I come from a computer science background and the languages I'm most familiar with are Java, C# and C++. In these languages your memory footprint is always in the back of your mind and I've been taught to destroy objects that are not in use.

I've recently got an internship as a web dev. I'm getting up to speed with various practices and doing a bit of web design which I haven't done in a while, at least not properly. In one of my sites I have a few images that appear on the screen, then move out of the viewport never to be seen again.

Would it be beneficial to .hide() the elements in question? Would it reduce the memory footprint enough to make it worth it? Would it reduce the footprint at all? A co-worker said it wouldn't be worth it as the hit is taken on page load but he wasn't totally sure.

Comment: Hiding an element does not remove it from the DOM.

Comment: As Pointy notes, hiding an element does not remove it from the DOM, so no win there, but it is possible for an offscreen element to affect scrolling performance.

Comment: So it does have _some_ benefit? Is there any way to remove an element from the DOM?

Comment: `Would it reduce the memory footprint enough to make it worth it?` this really varies on the situation.

Comment: Hiding via `display: none` does improve rendering performance as those elements are removed from layout/reflow.  `visibility:hidden` still impacts layout/reflow but not paint.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, hiding the element still leaves it in the DOM (Document Object Model). Personally, If I had something moving off screen and then not needed I would use the jQuery [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to physically remove it from the DOM. It may make a difference to performance depending on the size of the image and the amount of images that this is happening to.

Like I've said, I like my DOM to be clean and tidy without any unnecessary clutter, so I would remove them, but that's just me.

**EDIT:** Looking into it a bit more, it appears that removing the element from the DOM does not free the memory associated with it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785258/how-to-remove-dom-elements-without-memory-leaks/3785323#3785323)). It seems that it is dependant on the DOM implementation when the memory is freed ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785258/how-to-remove-dom-elements-without-memory-leaks/3786861#3786861)). Physically reusing the nodes looks like the most efficient way to go.

Comment: Removing the element from the DOM doesn't directly free memory the way deallocating an object would, but it allows the JavaScript engine's GC to potentially free memory on it's next pass (unless you have left in references to the removed node in which case you have a leak).

Comment: Yes, that's what I've said and as you've mentioned the GC could potentially free the memory, but there is no guarantee. That would depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy gave the correct answer (as a comment). No - it does very little to hide it because it's still in memory because the element (and all of it's children) are still in the DOM. It MAY make painting a little faster in scrollable/transformable areas (but it may not) but it certainly doesn't decrease the memory consumption of your app simply by hiding it.