# adding divs and clearing container repeatedly makes memory grow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple test page where I have a container.

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Once the page is ready I create an interval of 1 second where canvas is emptied,  3000 divs are created and appended to the canvas.

```
var id = 0;
var canvas;

$(document).ready(function(){
    canvas = $("#canvas");
    addElements();
});

function addElement(){
    for(var i= 0 ; i < 3000; i++){
        var html = "<div class=\"element\" id='div_id"+ id + "'>" + id + "</div>";
        canvas.append(html);
        id++;
    }
}

function addElements(){
    addElement();
    setInterval(function(){
    //canvas.empty();
        canvas.find("*").off();
        canvas.children().remove();
    },1000);
}
```

Any ideas on why the memory keeps growing like 3MB every second?

Here is a [sample Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rdJoFcuRCvUjb9SdHDqx?p=info)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The removed divs are probably still in the memory.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785258/how-to-remove-dom-elements-without-memory-leaks