# Permanent slowdown after adding and removing HTML elements: What causes it and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a project in Javascript that is mostly on run on a canvas, but also involves dynamically creating a lot of menus in the DOM.  I am not using JQuery, instead I am using a custom function that creates an element using document.createElement and then adds it to a parent with appendChild.  To remove elements, I use element.parentNode.removeChild(element).  Elements created can be of any type; inputs, images, and so on.

The problem is that after creating and removing elements a lot of times, the page starts to slow down significantly, and this worsens steadily the more elements are created and removed, even though there is no point where an especially large number of elements exist at once.  The Javascript does not slow down, though; the main update loop is fine, but mouse events and everything related to manipulating the DOM becomes slow until the page is reloaded.

I have experienced similar issues before, but have generally ignored them because they did not involve creating and removing large numbers of elements to the same degree as this one.

The only guess I have for a cause is that elements created by document.createElement continue to exist in memory even if their reference is cleared and they are removed from the visible part of the DOM.  Or perhaps removing a parent element does not properly remove all of its children, even though they seem to be gone.

My question is: Are created elements retained by the DOM even when they are not visible and no JS variable points to them, and can this be the cause of slowdown?  If so, how do I destroy a DOM element properly?

Comment: if you attach any event to the created elements, be sure to remove them before removing the element from the DOM.
Another possible cause could be that you retain references in memory to the created elements. Like, if you create an element and assign it to a variable, and that variable remains reachable, the element cannot be garbage collected.

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato: This was the issue!  Many of the menus use a custom canvas element with many event listeners, and I wasn't clearing them properly.  After fixing that it works!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

> The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part
>   of the DOM.  With the first syntax-form shown, you may reuse the
>   removed node later in your code, via the oldChild object reference. 
>   In the second syntax-form however, there is no oldChild reference
>   kept, so assuming your code has not kept any other reference to the
>   node elsewhere, it will immediately become unusable and irretrievable,
>   and will usually be automatically deleted from memory after a short
>   time.

And you can try something described as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3785323/1201725):

```
var garbageBin;
window.onload = function ()
{
if (typeof(garbageBin) === 'undefined')
    {
    //Here we are creating a 'garbage bin' object to temporarily 
    //store elements that are to be discarded
    garbageBin = document.createElement('div');
    garbageBin.style.display = 'none'; //Make sure it is not displayed
    document.body.appendChild(garbageBin);
    }
function discardElement(element)
    {
    //The way this works is due to the phenomenon whereby child nodes
    //of an object with it's innerHTML emptied are removed from memory

    //Move the element to the garbage bin element
    garbageBin.appendChild(element);
    //Empty the garbage bin
    garbageBin.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Where you can delete your dom element like:

```
discardElement(yourDomElement);
```

Comment: That's like a Recycle Bin on the Desktop, neat.

Comment: Even though the issue turned out to be something else, this is still a nice trick!  Also much more straightforward than the whole element.parent.removeChild(element) method of removing elements.